# What 're opened TCP port android need to be connected on?

Tags: wi-fi, google-account, networking, wifi-direct, udp

We've an android TV connected on a restricted WIFI network. Its IP adress is fixed. My problem only the web browser is working well. All other application can not go on the web or synchronize.
We got this netstat:

```
 u0_a67@android:/ $ netstat
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:38388 :::*
LISTEN
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:39643 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:34495 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:46563 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:46332 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:53406 ::ffff:14.17.41.151:443
ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:57860 ::ffff:103.7.30.158:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:39039 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:36796 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:53894 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:53360 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:34809 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:50549 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:38316 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:43701 ::ffff:157.169.25.15:80
CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.212.127.251:38207 ::ffff:216.58.198.14:80
ESTABLISHED
udp6       0      0 :::56331               :::*                   CLOSE
udp6       0      0 :::56456               :::*                   CLOSE
udp6       0    688 :::1900                :::*                   CLOSE
udp6       0      0 :::1900                :::*                   CLOSE
udp6       0      0 :::51117               :::*                   CLOSE
u0_a67@android:/ $
```

Regarding on the web information, we opened the TCP port 5228 in OUTPUT mode and we opened the  TCP port 38388 in INPUT mode as it's in listen status in the netstat.

That doesn't solve the problem.
Any idea about the list of TCP port need to be opened on the network for android working?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Android TV will stream the RTP (video stream) on a random port that varies all the time... you need to allow the internal Android TV device to use UPnP or to initiate traffic on any port and allow at least Restricted Cone NAT to occur or it will not function.

Comment: Thanks Where could I find any documentation about that ??

Comment: I don't have any documentation to that regard, and could not find any... it was a trial and error learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem configuring the closest time than universal time,  manually.  Google play connected itself well. After I configured  the ntp server in the network.